# error handling in shell script to stop flow execution on next line

Tags: shell

I would like to setup a error handling on my shell script where is my invocation of script fail with error, I should be able to stop the executin and flow should nt go on next line.

Like In my main script, I am making call to below script

```
sh /usr/oracle/StopServer.sh
```

if this script fail with error, my next script on this main file should not execute.. pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the return value of the command execution, one way to do this is:

```
sh /usr/oracle/StopServer.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # exit or take action
fi
```

it should do the trick

Comment: Hi, I have tried this option but system is still taking me to next script available in file. its not terminating the flow

Comment: In that case you might want to double check what the exit code of the script is, if it does exit with an error code other than 0 as it should if there is an error then our solutions will work. try echoing the result of the script to see what it is doing. So you're saying that the inside of that if block is being executed, right?

Comment: run `sh /usr/oracle/StopServer.sh` on command line and then `echo $?` and tell whats the value

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
sh /usr/oracle/StopServer.sh && sh my_next_line_that_only_happens_if_Stop_server_exits_without_error
```

For more information, the && operator in bash (and most languages) exhibits [McCarthy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which is basically just lazy evaluation for boolean conditionals. what this means is that for an and (&&) then the second term of the and expression will only be evaluated if the first part is true (because otherwise the result is garuanteed to be false. Similarly if we did A || B (or) B would only be executed if A were false, which means it returned with an exit code of 0 and thus failed. If you had a program that you wanted to execute if the program exited normally and another that you want to execute if it exited with a failed state (I'm going to call them normal and fail) then you could execute them like so:

```
sh condition.sh && sh normal.sh || sh fail.sh
```

EDIT:

```
if [ sh condition.sh ]; then
  # do whatever
else
 #this is what to do if it failed
fi
```

EDIT #2:

If you want to see what happens try running this:

```
if [ ls -badoption ] ; then
echo "passed "
else
echo "failed"
fi
# result follows
# zsh: parse error: condition expected: ls
# failed
```

it will fail as there is a bad option and failed will be run, if you had just put ls it would have echoed passed, this is where you can either exit or run the script depending on what path you take.

Comment: Thanks Mike but this option only applicable when u have only series of script.

Comment: after each script, I do some directory change and other data logic.. then only run next script.. so above option will not work

Comment: so put all these directory changes into a script, or into an if block.

Comment: I added an if block as an example, the point of this is the result of a script is a boolean condition that can be tested against, either in short form with 'and' && and 'or' || or in longer form with an 'if' block